# Proving that the union of two nowhere dense sets is a nowhere dense set.

Tags: general-topology

I have been asked to prove that the union of two nowhere dense sets is nowhere dense.

Let us take a topological space $X$ containing three points $a,b,c$. The open sets of $X$ are $\{\{a,b\},\{c\},\emptyset,X\}$. Clearly $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are nowhere dense. However, $\{a\}\cup\{b\}=\{a,b\}$ is not, as it contains the open set $\{a,b\}$.

Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: @mookid- Why not? What am I missing?

Comment: What is the closure of $\{a\}$?

Comment: $\{a\}$ is not nowhere dence, as its closure $\{a,b\}$ contains open set $\{a,b\}$

Comment: Ah. True. I was trying to construct a more complicated situation and got confused somewhere.